# How to concat strings in a jsonb array in a psql query?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to dynamically concat strings in a `jsonb` array in my `psql` query which is as follows :

```
with cte as (select generate_series(1, 3) as num) select '["name", "number"||cte.num]'::jsonb as res from cte;
```

But I am getting this error :

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...e as (select generate_series(1, 5) as num) select '["name", ...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "|" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ["name", "number"|...
```

So, here I am generating numbers from 1 to 3 and I want to append those numbers with "number" string in my `jsonb` array. This is what I want in my result:

```
         res                 
----------------------
 ["name", "number1"]
 ["name", "number2"]
 ["name", "number3"]
```

Please tell me how do I get this. Thanks.

Comment: @no_one- you can try `concat_ws()` Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT ( '["name", "number'|| num ||'"]' )::jsonb as res 
FROM generate_series(1, 3) num
```

You were adding the pipes as characters after an element in a list. You should first build the array string (in parenthesis), and then convert it to `jsonb`.

Comment: Thanks @MkWTF, this helped. So, now I have rewritten my query as : with cte as (select generate_series(1,3) num) select ('["name", "number' || cte.num || '"]')::jsonb from cte;